# Select columns of a particular data type in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, types

I am looking for a piece of information, but the table I'm looking at has dozens of columns, and I can't remember the exact name of the column. I only know that it is of a `date` type. Is there a way to select only `date` columns so that it will be easier to find the name of the column?

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM "MySchema"."MyTable"
WHERE {column.data_type} = 'date'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `information_schema.columns` view:

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'MySchema' and table_name = 'MyTable' and data_type = 'date';
```

Now that you have the names of the columns of type `date`, you can use that information create a view that selects only the values of such columns.

Comment: There can be more than one table named `MyTable`. Always specify values for `table_catalog` and `table_schema`, as well as for `table_name`. There is no column named `column_type` in `information_schema.columns`.